# How to implement polymorphic JPA entities with generic relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, metamodel

I'm trying to use JPA 2.0 to create polymorphic entities with generic relations. There should be two tables, an event table and a notification table. Inside those table are concrete entities that are related to one another, like so:

```
Event  <---------- Notification<X extends Event>
 |                      |
LoginEvent <------ LoginNotification extends Notification<LoginEvent>
```

Logically this should be possible in hibernate, as it is possible in SQL:

```
+----------+    +----------+
| Event    |    | Notif    |
+----------+    +----------+
|          |    | Id       |
| Id       | <- | Evt_id   |
| Type     | <- | Type     |
| ...      |    | ...      |
+----------+    +----------+
```

This is what I have:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class Event{

...
}

@Entity
public class LoginEvent extends Event{

...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class Notification<X extends Event>{

 @ManyToOne(optional=false, targetEntity=Event.class)
 @JoinColumn
 private X event;

...
}

@Entity
public class LoginNotification extends Notification<LoginEvent>{

...
}
```

Using this code, I can persist and fetch any Event, Notification, LoginEvent, or NotificationEvent, but it falls down when I try to use the `LoginNotification_.event` relation in my JPA 2.0 metamodel queries. [This issue](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/METAGEN-29) explains something similar.

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<NotificationEntity, EventEntity> event;
```

When I try to do a join in a criteria query, I get an error:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<LoginNotification> query = cb.createQuery(LoginNotification.class);
Root<LoginNotification> root = query.from(LoginNotification.class);

//  This line complains: Type mismatch: cannot convert from
//  Join<LoginNotification,Event> to Join<LoginNotification,LoginEvent>
Join<LoginNotification, LoginEvent> join = 
root.join(LoginNotification_.event, JoinType.INNER);
```

I can get around this error, by adding a new `SingularAttribute` to the `LoginNotification_` metamodel, but this fails in execution:

```
public abstract class LoginNotification_ extends Notification_ {

    // Adding this Removes Type mismatch error, but causes run-time error
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<LoginNotification, LoginEvent> event; 

    ...
}
```

According to some posts, generic relations won't work ([How to handle JPA annotations for a pointer to a generic interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808251/how-to-handle-jpa-annotations-for-a-pointer-to-a-generic-interface)), but by using a `@ManyToOne(optional=false, targetEntity=Event.class)` annotation, we can get them to behave. Unfortunately, the generics seem to break the JPA criteria query.

Are there any suggestions on how I can perform this lookup? I can use `LoginNotification.getEvent()` in my code, but I cannot use `LoginNotification_.event` in my JPA metamodel joins. What's the alternative to using generics to accomplish this?

@Pascal Thivent - Can you answer this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution to this is to avoid using the 'join' function and do a full cross join instead:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<LoginNotification> query = cb.createQuery(LoginNotification.class);
Root<LoginNotification> notfRoot = query.from(LoginNotification.class);
Root<LoginEvent> eventRoot = query.from(LoginEvent.class);
...
query.where(cb.equals(notfRoot.get(Notification_.event), eventRoot.get(Event_.id)), ...(other criteria));
```

I would assume that a decent query optimizer should make short work of this, but if anyone has any insight on the efficiency of this approach I would be keen to hear it!

Comment: Excellent, I used to write my joins this way in SQL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried you code for generic, @logan .

But I finally found the simplest way is let `T` implements `Serializable`

```
@Entity
public class IgsSubject extends BasicObject implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5387429446192609471L;
```